# java - saving data for minimal file size - as byte objects instead of text?

Tags: java

my java code generates and logs a large number of data to file as it runs at 10-60fps of up to several days. each time point has the following entries

timestamp (long), x coordinate (int - 0-2000), y coordinate (int - 0-1000), grayscale pixel value (byte), direction (short), length (short), width (short), other value (int)

not surprisingly i am trying to minimize file size of the logged data and was hoping to pick your brain on the best strategy for doing this. i have explored two fundamental approaches ... writing ascii or saving binary objects

obj:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePathString));
ObjectOutputStream fw_obj = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
fw_obj.writeObject(aString);
```

or

txt:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePathString));
Writer fw_txt = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
fw_txt.write(aString);
```

the object approach has been less effective than what i had hoped. file sizes are roughly equal for the two. any suggestions on what strategy should be best and opinions for pushing this to the max would be very appreciated. Eternally grateful,

Comment: Compress it. `GZIPOutputStream`.

Comment: ooooh, nice. yes, when i save my data to bytes, and then compress it, it really crunches things down a whole bunch more. i think i am posting the question about performance in writing to it as a separate question. that is a great lead and i am digging into this right now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best strategy is to convert the values to bytes and then write them to the file

Long + int + int + byte + short + short +short + int

8 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 4 = 27 bytes per data

Comment: thanks a huge bunch for the pointer. sounds about as minimal as it goes, i just have to keep track with what is where so i can read it in again as intended. i assume there is not a drawback to having a line at the top as header with meta info and info on byte borders to inform later parsing. i also assume the option with the BufferedWriter wrapped OutputStreamWriter is the most efficient framework to write the bytes to the file. thanks again and much obliged

Comment: actually, i just need the FileOutputStream and i am good. me thinks

Comment: sumary ... i ended up wrapping the FileOutputStream in a BufferedWriter because my writes are on many small byte[], and gathering them into bigger chunks for the write makes a lot of sense. i am performance testing what cost Siguza's suggestion for gzipping imposes. i get huge reductions in files size with it, and i am hoping that i find some free cycles that i can burn on this :-) thanks again